# Bash with recursion into subfolders containing spaces

Tags: bash, find, exiftool

I am trying to add unique IDs to the pictures taken with my DSLR. The DSLR saves both a RAW file (NEF) and an actual image file (JPG). These pairs represents the same image, and should therefore have the same image ID.

I tried the following bash script which is kind of working. However, since there are spaces in my folder names, I have to run the script from each subfolder instead of from the parent pictures folder.

How do I redo the script, so it would allow subfolder whose names contains spaces?

```
#!/bin/bash

LIB="."

for file in $(find $LIB -name '*.NEF'); do
        UUID=`uuidgen`
        exiftool -q -if 'not $ImageUniqueID' "$file" -ImageUniqueID=$UUID -overwrite_original;
        exiftool -q -if 'not $ImageUniqueID' "${file%.NEF}.JPG" -ImageUniqueID=$UUID -overwrite_original;
done
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).

Comment: Use something like this instead: `find "$LIB" -type f -name '*.NEF' -print0 |while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r fl;do ....<code using "$fl">... ;done` . This use null as separator and should work in all cases. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup time of exiftool is its biggest performance hit and running once for each file will significantly increase the run time, especially when processing hundreds, if not thousands, of files.

Unless you specifically need the type of id that uuidgen generates, exiftool has to the ability to create a unique id with the `NewGUID` tag.  As listed on the [Extra Tags page](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Extra.html), it consists of "a new, random GUID with format YYYYmmdd-HHMM-SSNN-PPPP-RRRRRRRRRRRR, where Y=year, m=month, d=day, H=hour, M=minute, S=second, N=file sequence number in hex, P=process ID in hex, and R=random hex number".  A hashtag can be added to the end of the tag name (e.g. `NewGUID#`) to suppress the dashes.

You could then run
`exiftool -overwrite_original -ext Nef -r -q -if 'not $ImageUniqueID' '-ImageUniqueID<NewGUID' .`
to write all the nef files recursively (enabled by the `-r` option) and then run a second command to copy the `ImageUniqueID` from the nefs to the jpgs with
`exiftool -overwrite_original -ext jpg -r -q -TagsFromFile %d%f.nef -ImageUniqueID .`

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop *or* `find`, not both.

```
# With a loop
shopt -s globstar
for f in "$LIB"/**/*.NEF; do
  uuid=$(uuidgen)
  exiftool -q -if 'not $ImageUniqueID' "$file" -ImageUniqueID=$uuid -overwrite_original
  exiftool -q -if 'not $ImageUniqueID' "${file%.NEF}.JPG" -ImageUniqueID=$uuid -overwrite_original
done

# With find
find "$LIB" -name "*.NEF" -exec sh -c '
     uuid=$(uuidgen)
     exiftool -q -if "not \$ImageUniqueID" "$1" -ImageUniqueID=$uuid -overwrite_original;
     exiftool -q -if "not \$ImageUniqueID" "${1%.NEF}.JPG" -ImageUniqueID=$uuid -overwrite_original
     ' _ {} \;
```

Comment: The looping example does not seem to work on macOS; the find example does, however.

Comment: `globstar` requires `bash` 4 (released in early 2009), but macOS still ships version 3.2 (for licensing reasons, IIUC). For any scripting that requires more than a POSIX-compliant shell, you are better off installing a modern version of `bash`, or using `zsh` (a modern version of which does ship in macOS).

Comment: (An up-to-date version of `ksh` also ships with macOS, but for various reasons I've never really used it; it's an option as well.)